# Can a stringtemplate ModelAdaptor fall back to default stringtemplate property evaluation?

Tags: stringtemplate-4

It appears that, if I supply a ModelAdaptor for a class I supply to stringtemplate, then I have to respond to every property I want accessible in a template.  I'd *like* to be able to be able to implement getProperty for properties that don't follow the normal naming convention, but let the default behavior handle "normal" properties.  Is there a class I can subclass to get the normal behavior (perhaps just calling super() when it's not a property I've implemented, or a method I can call to get the default stringtemplate logic)?

That is, I'd like to handle just the exceptional properties in the adaptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the [`ObjectModelAdaptor`](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/src/org/stringtemplate/v4/misc/ObjectModelAdaptor.java) class.

Override the `getProperty` method to include a `try`/`catch` block, and use your custom handling in the `catch` block for a `STNoSuchPropertyException`.

```
public class MyModelAdaptor extends ObjectModelAdaptor {
  @Override
  public Object getProperty(Interpreter interp, ST self, Object o, Object property, String propertyName) {
    try {
      return super.getProperty(interp, self, o, property, propertyName);
    } catch (STNoSuchPropertyException ex) {
      throw new STNoSuchPropertyException("TODO: custom handling goes here");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this gives me what I was looking for, though I'm thinking that I would make the call to super.getProperty(...) once I had exhausted the properties that I code in my ModelAdaptor, and let the super class decide to throw the exception.  That would allow me to override a property that ObjectModelAdaptor might otherwise handle.  I'm assuming this would work as well.  (I'll give it a try tomorrow). Thanks once again for the quick response.  This would be good documentation to have in the documentation for ModelAdaptors.